# Resample dataframe by random subset of years

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, subset

I have a dataset of 59 years worth of daily rainfall data.

I'd like to resample the data by 6 randomly selected years 1,000 times, using the entire year of data for each of the 6 years (so 2190 observations in total).

Currently, the line of code I'm using only selects a random set of observations but not necessarily within the same year.

duration6 <- duration[sample(1:nrow(duration$WrYear), 2190, replace=TRUE),]

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated!

- Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the rows by whether they are in the year of interest.

```
duration6 <- duration[duration$WrYear %in% sample(unique(duration$WrYear), 6, replace=TRUE),]
```

You are to randomly sample 6 of the 59 years, and choosing the rows that are in one of those 6 years.